# Jwt Key is not valid for HmacSHA256

Tags: jwt

*i have a problem that when i create claim after signing it while sending  i am getting key is not valid, not able to get the reason ..*

```
*code:*
OctetSequenceJsonWebKey key = OctJwkGenerator.generateJwk(2048);
JsonWebSignature jws = new JsonWebSignature();
 jws.setKey(key.getKey());
 jws.setPayload(claims.toJson());
jws.setAlgorithmHeaderValue(AlgorithmIdentifiers.HMAC_SHA256);
signedJWT = jws.getCompactSerialization();
return signedJWT;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Hmac algorithms, you are supposed to use an octet key. 
From your code, I can see you are loading a RSA key (`RsaJsonWebKey`)

Comment: i changed it to OctJwkGenerator.generateJwk(2048) still it is giving same error

Comment: Can you modify your question with the updated code and indicate which line is responsible of your error. Thanks.